# Make drop down menu to have flexible width

Tags: css

Is possible to make the `#navbar > li > ul` to have flexible width (so it resizes depending on the text) rather than inherit the `width` from the parent `#navbar > li`?

```css
#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 1em;
}
#navbar li ul {
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 1.5em;
}
#navbar li li {
    margin: .5em;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}
#navbar > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navbar">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make inner UL `white-space: nowrap;` and set inner LI to `display: block`:

```css
#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 1em;
}

#navbar li ul {
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 1.5em;
}

#navbar li li {
    margin: .5em 1em .5em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar > li:hover > ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
}

#navbar > li:hover > ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="navbar">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this code

```css
#navbar{
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

#navbar li ul { /* possible full width? */
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

}

#navbar li li {
    padding: 0;
}

#navbar > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;

}
#navbar a{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
#navbar a:hover{color#333;}
```

```html
<ul id="navbar">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item A</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item B</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, just change your css like this

```
#navbar {
    position: relative;
}

#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1em 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 1em;
}

#navbar li ul { /* possible full width? */
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 1.5em;
    width: 100%;
}

#navbar li li {
    margin: .5em 1em .5em 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
}

#navbar > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lqnz1wme/

Answer (score 0):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/fa94a5oo/3/

```
#navbar li {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 75px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add white-space property to `#navbar li li:`

```
#navbar li li {
    margin: .5em 1em .5em 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```