# Dropdown Menu's Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built this fiddle using jQuery to select a top menu that displays a second menu div using a succession of toggling CSS and hide/showing with jQuery.

This works, but I'm a beginner and relatively sure there is a cleaner easier, shorter way to write this code. For example an easier way to assign classes and affect all the divs or better use of the `this`. Any help is appreciated.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrhugo/u4zauzhz/6/)

```js
$("#home").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  $(".secondMenu").hide();
  $(".toggle").removeClass("selected");
  $("#home1").toggle();
});

$("#profile").click(function() {
  $(".toggle").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  $(".secondMenu").hide();
  $("#profile1").toggle();
});

$("#resume").click(function() {
  $(".toggle").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  $(".secondMenu").hide();
  $("#resume1").toggle();
});

$("#work").click(function() {
  $(".toggle").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  $(".secondMenu").hide();
  $("#work1").toggle();
});

$("#adventures").click(function() {
  $(".toggle").removeClass("selected");
  $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  $(".secondMenu").hide();
  $("#adventures1").toggle();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#topBar {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #990000;
}
#mainMenu {
  margin: 25px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}
#mainMenu li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  color: white;
}
.selected {
  background-color: #3E0C0D;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
}
.secondMenu {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3E0C0D;
  clear: right;
  display: none;
}
.secondMenu ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 8px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.secondMenu li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 80%;
}
#clearDiv {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="topBar">
    <ul id="mainMenu">
      <li class="toggle" id="home">Home</li>
      <li class="toggle" id="profile">Profile</li>
      <li class="toggle" id="resume">Resume</li>
      <li class="toggle" id="work">Work Examples</li>
      <li style="border:none" class="toggle" id="adventures">Adventures</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="secondMenu" id="home1">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>home</li>
      <li style="border:none">home</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="secondMenu" id="profile1">
    <ul>
      <li>prof</li>
      <li>prof</li>
      <li>prof</li>
      <li>prof</li>
      <li>prof</li>
      <li>prof</li>
      <li style="border:none">prof</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="secondMenu" id="resume1">
    <ul>
      <li>res</li>
      <li>res</li>
      <li>res</li>
      <li>res</li>
      <li>res</li>
      <li>res</li>
      <li style="border:none">res</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="secondMenu" id="work1">
    <ul>
      <li>egs</li>
      <li>egs</li>
      <li>egs</li>
      <li>egs</li>
      <li>egs</li>
      <li>egs</li>
      <li style="border:none">home</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="secondMenu" id="adventures1">
    <ul>
      <li>adv</li>
      <li>adv</li>
      <li>adv</li>
      <li>adv</li>
      <li>adv</li>
      <li>adv</li>
      <li style="border:none">home</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="clearDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't really need javascript, all menus can be build in pure css nowadays. You can also add animations, which will work in modern browsers. First result in google http://purecss.io/menus/

Comment: take a look of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369240/make-drop-down-menu-flexible-width i believe it's the easiest way to do dropdown menus, you need to remove that `.hover` action in css and put it into jQuery as click action. But it's your choice whether to use do that, maybe for your next project. As things are working fine already at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yerkopalma/u4zauzhz/7/)

Here is the code

```
function dropdownMenu(triger, target) {
$("#"+triger).click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $(".secondMenu").hide();
    $(".toggle").removeClass("selected");
    $("#"+target).toggle();
})    
}

dropdownMenu("home", "home1");
dropdownMenu("profile", "profile1");
dropdownMenu("resume", "resume1");
dropdownMenu("work", "work1");
dropdownMenu("adventures", "adventures1");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simplify your js code this way:

```
$('.toggle').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
        $(".secondMenu").hide();
        $(".toggle").removeClass("selected");
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id')+'1').toggle();
    });
});
```

this code searches for each element with a 'toggle' class in your html. No need to repeat all of them.

edit with the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/u4zauzhz/12/)

Answer (score 0):

basically you should try to reduce your code as much as possible..
so you can try this.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="topBar">
    <ul id="mainMenu">
        <li class="toggle" id="home">Home</li>
        <li class="toggle" id="profile">Profile</li>
        <li class="toggle" id="resume">Resume</li>
        <li class="toggle" id="work">Work Examples</li>
        <li style="border:none" class="toggle" id="adventures">Adventures</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="secondMenu home">
    <ul>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>home</li>
        <li>home</li>
        <li style="border:none">home</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="secondMenu profile">
    <ul>
        <li>prof</li>
        <li>prof</li>
        <li>prof</li>
        <li>prof</li>
        <li>prof</li>
        <li>prof</li>
        <li style="border:none">prof</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="secondMenu resume">
    <ul>
        <li>res</li>
        <li>res</li>
        <li>res</li>
        <li>res</li>
        <li>res</li>
        <li>res</li>
        <li style="border:none">res</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="secondMenu work">
    <ul>
        <li>egs</li>
        <li>egs</li>
        <li>egs</li>
        <li>egs</li>
        <li>egs</li>
        <li>egs</li>
        <li style="border:none">home</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="secondMenu adventures">
    <ul>
        <li>adv</li>
        <li>adv</li>
        <li>adv</li>
        <li>adv</li>
        <li>adv</li>
        <li>adv</li>
        <li style="border:none">home</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="clearDiv"></div>
```

js

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
    $(".secondMenu").hide();
    $("."+$(this).attr("id")).show();
    $(".toggle").removeClass("selected");
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All other solutions are incorrect, because it doesn't show the active state of the link. My solution does show the active state:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function () {        
        $('.toggle').removeClass('selected');
        $('.secondMenu').removeClass('show');
        
        var $this = $(this),
            $name = $(this).attr('id'),
            $name = '#' + $name + '1';
        
        $this.addClass('selected');                
        $($name).addClass('show');
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    font-family:"HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
#topBar {
    margin:0px;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #990000;
}
#mainMenu {
    margin:25px 0 0 0;
    list-style:none;
    float:right;
}
#mainMenu li {
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid white;
    padding:0 5px 0 5px;
    color:white;
}
.selected {
    background-color:#3E0C0D;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100%;
}
.secondMenu {
    position:relative;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #3E0C0D;
    clear:right;
    display:none;
}

.secondMenu.show {
    display: block;
}
.secondMenu ul {
    float:right;
    margin: 8px 0 0 0;
    list-style:none;
}
.secondMenu li {
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid white;
    padding:0 5px 0 5px;
    color:white;
    font-size: 80%;
}
#clearDiv {
    clear:both;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="topBar">
        <ul id="mainMenu">
            <li class="toggle" id="home">Home</li>
            <li class="toggle" id="profile">Profile</li>
            <li class="toggle" id="resume">Resume</li>
            <li class="toggle" id="work">Work Examples</li>
            <li style="border:none" class="toggle" id="adventures">Adventures</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="secondMenu" id="home1">
        <ul>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li>home</li>
            <li style="border:none">home</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="secondMenu" id="profile1">
        <ul>
            <li>prof</li>
            <li>prof</li>
            <li>prof</li>
            <li>prof</li>
            <li>prof</li>
            <li>prof</li>
            <li style="border:none">prof</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="secondMenu" id="resume1">
        <ul>
            <li>res</li>
            <li>res</li>
            <li>res</li>
            <li>res</li>
            <li>res</li>
            <li>res</li>
            <li style="border:none">res</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="secondMenu" id="work1">
        <ul>
            <li>egs</li>
            <li>egs</li>
            <li>egs</li>
            <li>egs</li>
            <li>egs</li>
            <li>egs</li>
            <li style="border:none">home</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="secondMenu" id="adventures1">
        <ul>
            <li>adv</li>
            <li>adv</li>
            <li>adv</li>
            <li>adv</li>
            <li>adv</li>
            <li>adv</li>
            <li style="border:none">home</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="clearDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version:

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $(".secondMenu").hide();
    $(".toggle").removeClass("selected");
    $("#"+this.dataset.id+"1").toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DariuszMusielak/gcnhw2dk/